# how to scale a contour's height by a factor?

Tags: android, ios, opencv, computer-vision, opencv3.0

I am trying to scan a passport page using the phone's camera using OpenCV. 
[image: marked passport sample]

In the above image the contour marked in red is my ROI (will need a top view of that). Performing segmentation I can [detect the MRZ area](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/11/30/detecting-machine-readable-zones-in-passport-images/). And the pages should have a fixed aspect ratio. Is there a way to scale the green contour using the aspect ratio to approximate the red one? I have tried finding the corners of the green rect using `approxPolyDP`, and then scaling that rect and finally doing a perspective warp to get the top view. The problem is that the perspective rotation is not accounted for while doing the rectangular scaling, so the final rect is often wrong.

Often I get an output as marked in the following image
[image]

**Update:** Adding a little more explanation

In regard to the 1st image (assuming the red rect will always have a constant aspect ratio),

- My goal: is to crop out the red marked portion and then get a top view
- My approach: detect the MRZ/green rect -> now assume the bottom edge of the green rect is the same as the red one (close enough) -> So I got the width and two corners of the rect -> calculate other two corners using the height/aspect ratio
- Problem: my above calculation doesn't output the red rect, instead it outputs the green rect in the 2nd image (may be because those quadrilaterals aren't rectangles, angle between edges aren't either 0 or 90 degrees)

Comment: could you add examples of failure cases?

Comment: you should try affine transformation/image warping

Comment: @JeruLuke I am doing a transform to get the top view, that's not the problem. The problem is how to get the red contour/rectangle from the green one in the 1st image? Just finding out the top corners from aspect ratio often gives a rectangle as shown in 2nd image.

Comment: @Mehedi I am still confused at what you exactly want...

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand your main goal is to get the top view of the passport page when its photo is taken from arbitrary angle. 
Also as I understand your approach is the following:

1. Find MRZ and its wrapping polygon
2. Extend the MRZ polygon to the top - this would give you the page polygon
3. Warp perspective to get the top view.

And the main obstacle currently is to extend the polygon.

Please correct me If understood the goal incorrectly.

Extending a polygon is quiet easy from mathematical perspective. Points on each side of the polygon form a side line. If you draw the line further you can put there a new point. Programmatically it may look like this

```
new_left_top_x = old_left_bottom_x + (old_left_top_x - old_left_bottom_x) * pass_height_to_MRZ_height_ratio
new_left_top_y = old_left_bottom_y + (old_left_top_y - old_left_bottom_y) * pass_height_to_MRZ_height_ratio
```

The same can be done for the right part. This approach would also work with rotations up to 45 degrees.

However I'm afraid this approach would not give accurate results. I would suggest to detect the passport page itself instead of MRZ. The reason is that the page itself is quiet noticeable object on the photo and can be easily found by `findContours` function.

I wrote some code to illustrate the idea that detecting MRZ is not really necessary.

```
import os
import imutils
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2


# Thresholds
passport_page_aspect_ratio = 1.44
passport_page_coverage_ratio_threshold = 0.6
morph_size = (4, 4)


def pre_process_image(image):
    # Let's get rid of color first
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Then apply Otsu threshold to reveal important areas
    ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

    # erode white areas to "disconnect" them
    # and dilate back to restore their original shape
    morph_struct = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, morph_size)
    thresh = cv2.erode(thresh, morph_struct, anchor=(-1, -1), iterations=1)
    thresh = cv2.dilate(thresh, morph_struct, anchor=(-1, -1), iterations=1)

    return thresh


def find_passport_page_polygon(image):
    cnts = cv2.findContours(image, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
    cnts = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)

    for cnt in cnts:
        # compute the aspect ratio and coverage ratio of the bounding box
        # width to the width of the image
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
        ar = w / float(h)
        cr_width = w / float(image.shape[1])

        # check to see if the aspect ratio and coverage width are within thresholds
        if ar > passport_page_aspect_ratio and cr_width > passport_page_coverage_ratio_threshold:
            # approximate the contour with a polygon with 4 points
            epsilon = 0.02 * cv2.arcLength(cnt, True)
            approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, epsilon, True)
            return approx

    return None


def order_points(pts):
    # initialize a list of coordinates that will be ordered in the order:
    # top-left, top-right, bottom-right, bottom-left
    rect = np.zeros((4, 2), dtype="float32")
    pts = pts.reshape(4, 2)

    # the top-left point will have the smallest sum, whereas
    # the bottom-right point will have the largest sum
    s = pts.sum(axis=1)
    rect[0] = pts[np.argmin(s)]
    rect[2] = pts[np.argmax(s)]

    # now, compute the difference between the points, the
    # top-right point will have the smallest difference,
    # whereas the bottom-left will have the largest difference
    diff = np.diff(pts, axis=1)
    rect[1] = pts[np.argmin(diff)]
    rect[3] = pts[np.argmax(diff)]

    return rect


def get_passport_top_vew(image, pts):
    rect = order_points(pts)
    (tl, tr, br, bl) = rect

    # compute the height of the new image, which will be the
    # maximum distance between the top-right and bottom-right
    # y-coordinates or the top-left and bottom-left y-coordinates
    height_a = np.sqrt(((tr[0] - br[0]) ** 2) + ((tr[1] - br[1]) ** 2))
    height_b = np.sqrt(((tl[0] - bl[0]) ** 2) + ((tl[1] - bl[1]) ** 2))
    max_height = max(int(height_a), int(height_b))

    # compute the width using standard passport page aspect ratio
    max_width = int(max_height * passport_page_aspect_ratio)

    # construct the set of destination points to obtain the top view, specifying points
    # in the top-left, top-right, bottom-right, and bottom-left order
    dst = np.array([
        [0, 0],
        [max_width - 1, 0],
        [max_width - 1, max_height - 1],
        [0, max_height - 1]], dtype="float32")

    # compute the perspective transform matrix and apply it
    M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(rect, dst)
    warped = cv2.warpPerspective(image, M, (max_width, max_height))

    return warped


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True, help="path to images directory")
    args = vars(ap.parse_args())

    in_file = args["image"]
    filename_base = in_file.replace(os.path.splitext(in_file)[1], "")

    img = cv2.imread(in_file)

    pre_processed = pre_process_image(img)

    # Visualizing pre-processed image
    cv2.imwrite(filename_base + ".pre.png", pre_processed)

    page_polygon = find_passport_page_polygon(pre_processed)

    if page_polygon is not None:
        # Visualizing found page polygon
        vis = img.copy()
        cv2.polylines(vis, [page_polygon], True, (0, 255, 0), 2)
        cv2.imwrite(filename_base + ".bounds.png", vis)

        # Visualizing the warped top view of the passport page
        top_view_page = get_passport_top_vew(img, page_polygon)
        cv2.imwrite(filename_base + ".top.png", top_view_page)
```

The results I got:

[image: Passport page bound]
[image]

For better result it would be also good to compensate the camera aperture distortion.

Comment: I think this outputs exactly what the question asked. @Mehedi, if your question has been answered, you should accept the answer.