# What is the simplest way to crop out a block of text from a black background from a picture with image?

Tags: python, computer-vision

I want to extract images from a slide with white texts on a black background.

I have around 70 slides with a image on a black background and a paragraph of white text next to it or underneath it. The images are of different sizes and position in the slides. The texts are all white and never overlapping the images.

I want to just keep the image part.

I've tried the following method from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53151293/opencv-crop-out-text-areas-from-license), but i was not satisfied with the result.

I don't need anything fancy like understanding the texts. I don't even need the file to be perfectly cropped to the borders of the image. As Long as the text are not visible its fine. For example, it could be blocked. It should be fairly simple because its just white text on a black background.

Comment: depending on the file format your slides are in, computer-vision might not be the right approach here. So could you please share with us that information?

Comment: @Ente Hi! The slides are in one pdf file. I assume they are exported from a power point presentation. Thanks! :)